# Will C++ Builder 10.2 Tokyo support Android 9?

Tags: android, c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-tokyo

Is there any information about C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo supporting Android 9? I need to write application targeting Android API 28.

Currently supported target platforms are listed in this [table](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Supported_Target_Platforms).

I know, that C++Builder 10.3 Rio supports Android 9 as you can see [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Supported_Target_Platforms), but I cannot change IDE to newer version at the moment.

Comment: I'm surprised that there are people still using C++ Builder ...;)

Comment: What is it *specifically* you need API 28 for? If it's a small thing then perhaps it can be emulated in earlier API versions?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, one of our customers plans to buy devices with Android 9. I tested app on device with this version of Android and it didn't run. I saw only a message that this app is not targetting device's API. It is "for future", but it is good to be prepared :)

Comment: That seems more like a configuration problem, that you don't allow higher-level releases. AFAIK you can specify a *range* of API versions for your applications, perhaps the upper limit is 27 in your configuration?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, specifically - app is recording video with audio and taking photos from camera and library as well. I am a newbie in programming, I don't know, what part is causing the problem. Second app is working well on Adnroid 9, but it is only using ZXing barcode reader via intent. I suppose, this may be related to permissions or intents, but I am not sure.

Comment: If you have particular problem with some part of functionality then you can ask question here about specific code. Just make sure you provide [mcve] so others can reproduce your issue and potentially offer solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I tried writing in AndroidManifest.xml targetSdkVersion="28", but during build it automatically switches back to 14. This is, AFAIK, known issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949190/delphi-xe5-androidmanifest-can-not-set-minsdkversion-14-or-bigger)).

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, thank you, I will consider this :)

Comment: Unless you know how to implement all required functionality required by API 28 (huge task) don't set target 28. It will create more problems than it would solve. As far as ability to change manifest target is concerned (if there is a bug - AFAIK Delphi does not have that issue, I don't know about C++) there are possible workarounds.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, as I wrote under your answer, I will read your link and try to solve this problem and find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3):

Changes in underlying frameworks required to support newer Android API (including Android 9) are too big to be backported to 10.2 Tokyo. That includes both language flavors - Delphi and C++.

At the moment even Delphi Rio (initial release) does not have full support for Android 9. That may change in future Rio updates and/or subsequent 10.4 release.

Applications written with Tokyo can run on newer OS versions, but they will run in compatibility mode. You can manually change Android Manifest to target higher API version than default but then you must implement all features and behaviors expected by the target OS. If you fail to do so, such application will crash or misbehave.

Android 9 also introduces some changes that affect all applications regardless of their target API. those changes can also have impact on your application. [Android 9 Behavior changes: all apps](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all)

Comment: @Thank you for your input! For now we will stick to API below 28, but I will read what you linked in your answer and try to find out the solution.